# Can someone please translate the phrase, “Be remembered for nothing, but be remembered?”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Long story short, I wrote a poem that contained the line, “Be remembered for nothing, but be remembered.”

Now I want to use that phrase as a motto in a novel I am writing but have no knowledge of Latin grammar. This is meant to be a command for folks to be remembered for nothing particular, but remembered nevertheless.

I did some research and cobbled together the following but have no way to judge how accurate they are:

recordatus pro nihilo sed recordatus

in memoria sed pro nihilum reuocari

The challenge is that there are multiple verbs related to memory and remembering but I do not just want to say “remember nothing, but remember.”

I appreciate any help you all are willing to provide.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In "Be remembered for nothing," are you inviting people to be non-achievers? Therefore, is to be remembered for nothing a good thing? It may be that non-achievers will only be remembered by their friends/ relationships: which can last only as long as they do. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Michael. But I really do need more info to translate this. Can you tell us what you mean by this line? Can you post a the whole poem, or at least a larger part of it, which contains this line?